# ClickHouse ReplicatedMergeTrees configuration problems

Tags: sql, apache-zookeeper, yandex, columnstore, clickhouse

I have two tables on two different machines both running zookeeper as a daemon, one of them has myid 1 the other has myid 2.

The table is configured as such on the machine "1":

```
CREATE TABLE test(values)
ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/01/test', '1', date, timestamp, 8192)
```

The table is configured as such on the machine "2":

```
CREATE TABLE test(values)
ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/01/test', '2', date, timestamp, 8192)
```

The 01 in the '/clickhouse/tables/01/test' is probably the values messing with me... since I '{layer}-{shard}' with it.... but since I have no remote_servers configured I assumed I can just use any value and it wouldn't matter, since I don't want query distribution, just data duplication.

Also the tables seem to be "aware" of eachother since creating two tables with the replica number '2' or '1' results in an error saying such a table already exists.

Do I need to configure a remote_server by default if I want to use replication ? Do I need to configure zookeeper specifically for the tables I want to replicated ? Do you guys have any in-details examples of setting up data replication with clickhouse ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have done everything correctly. `{layer}-{shard}` part is optional - it just simplifies creation of similar tables on many servers. Bare minimum for configuring a replicated table is a path in zookeeper that is common for all replicas (by convention this path starts with `/clickhouse/tables/` but in fact any unique path will do) and an identifier that is unique to each replica (`'1'` and `'2'` are totally OK, but more descriptive names allowing you to identify the corresponding host are recommended).

Configuring `remote_servers` is not necessary for replication, but zookeeper is required. You can use a single zookeeper cluster for all replicated tables.

Comment: Is the path (e.g. /clickhouse/tables/) automatically 'created' by zookeeper. As in, if I have the same path for all the tables do I need to configure anything else in zookeeper ?

Comment: ClickHouse will automatically create the zookeeper path that is passed to ReplicatedMergeTree engine during engine creation, its nonexistent parents, and the necessary directory structure inside it. After the last replica table is dropped, this path will be deleted. So yes, everything should happen automatically.

What is the exact nature of your difficulties?

Comment: The exact error message that I'm getting currently is as follows (I get this after I insert data on one of the replicas): <Error> DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::queueTask()::<lambda(DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::LogEntryPtr&)>: Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, e.displayText() = Host not found: otherMachineHostname, e.what() = Host not found

Comment: Ok, the prvious was apparently an error that can be fixed editing /etc/hosts.

Comment: Now however I am getting this error: Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 111, e.displayText() = Connection refused, e.what() = Connection refused
Which might be config file related ? Maybe I need to change some security settings

Comment: You should update the question accordingly. The problem is that one replica cannot connect to the other using the hostname that this second replica advertised (is otherMachineHostname a placeholder or a real value?). Try setting `interserver_http_host` config parameter on the replica hosts to their respective host names.

Comment: Yes, one replica must be able to connect to the other on the `interserver_http_port`. Also the problem might be in the `listen_host` parameter - by default ClickHouse accepts connections only from localhost because of security concerns. Try allowing connections from one replica host to another (for example by setting a wildcard `listen_host`).

Comment: Yep, that was indeed the problem, I had ::1 in the listen_hosts, now I just replaced it with :: to allow all connections but I sadly enough have another error... with a stacktrace, but one I can't quite understand. I will post it here if you still have time to look at it. Though this is so far off from the original problems I had that I'm not sure it fits the question.

Comment: edit: Not, I can't post the stack trace, too long for comments. The error message is: <Error> DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::queueTask()::<lambda(DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::LogEntryPtr&)>: Code: 86, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Received error from remote server http://ryzen1:9009/?endpoint=DataPartsExchange:%2Fclickhouse%2Ftables%2FtestTable%2Freplicas%2F1&part=20170327_20170327_200_200_0&shard=&compress=false. HTTP status code: 400 Bad Request, body: , e.what() = DB::Exception, Stack trace:

Comment: Strange thing is... when I run curl -X GET 'url' on the urls that returned status 400 to clickhouse I actually get ~100 of binary.

Comment: Fixed, apparently I had a bad version of the source code that had a bug... my bug for not compiling from stable.